# Firebase cloud function with nested promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to send an email based on a collection onAdd event
the information i need to send the email comes from 3 different collections
so i was thinking to set all the data i need and then proceed to send the email, however , when i come to the actual email sending all the info is undefined, so clearly the variables are not set properly

here is my code

```
exports.sendRepairInitiatedEmail = functions.firestore.document('repairs/{id}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const repair = snap.data(); <--- this is set correctly
  let customer;
  let configuration;
  return admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('customers')
    .doc(repair.customerId)
    .get()
    .then(dbCustomer => {
      customer = dbCustomer; <--- customer seems undefined
      return admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('configuration')
        .where('clientId', '==', repair.clientId)
        .get()
        .then(conf => {
          configuration = conf; <-- configuration seems undefined
          console.log('Sending email to  ' + customer.customerEmail);
          const msg = {
            to: customer.customerEmail,
            from: configuration.companyEmail,
            templateId: 'sendGridid',
            dynamic_template_data: {
              name: customer.customerName,
              device: repair.device,
              accessCode: repair.accessCode,
              storeName: configuration.storeName,
              phone: configuration.phoneNumber,
            },
          };
          return sgMail.send(msg);
        });
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Repair initiated email successfully sent to ' + customer.customerName));
});
```

code also looks complicated and i want to avoid so much promise nesting
any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You can avoid nesting by using async/await syntax instead of promise callbacks.  You could also rework your code to never use `then` inside another `then`.  Handle the results in sequential `then` callbacks rather than nested callbacks.

Comment: hi @DougStevenson thanks for the comment but can you show a code example?

Comment: Check out my answer and see if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to nest so many promises, why don't you try something like this:

```
exports.sendRepairInitiatedEmail = functions.firestore.document('repairs/{id}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const repair = snap.data(); 
  let getCustomer = admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('customers')
    .doc(repair.customerId)
    .get();
  let getConfig = admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('configuration')
    .where('clientId', '==', repair.clientId)
    .get();
  return Promise.all([getCustomer, getConfig])
    .then(values => {
        const [customer, configuration] = values;
        console.log('Sending email to  ' + customer.customerEmail);
          const msg = {
            to: customer.customerEmail,
            from: configuration.companyEmail,
            templateId: 'sendGridid',
            dynamic_template_data: {
              name: customer.customerName,
              device: repair.device,
              accessCode: repair.accessCode,
              storeName: configuration.storeName,
              phone: configuration.phoneNumber,
            },
          };
          console.log('Repair initiated email successfully sent to ' + customer.customerName);
          return sgMail.send(msg);
    }); 
});
```

This code just uses all the returned values from the promises one after another without the need to make them available to a bigger scope.

Or alternatively, if possible you could turn the whole thing into async/await structure and it will look much cleaner, it will be something like this (untested):

```
exports.sendRepairInitiatedEmail = functions.firestore.document('repairs/{id}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const repair = snap.data(); 
    const customer = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('customers')
      .doc(repair.customerId)
      .get();
    const configuration = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('configuration')
      .where('clientId', '==', repair.clientId)
      .get();
    console.log('Sending email to  ' + customer.customerEmail);
    const msg = {
        to: customer.customerEmail,
        from: configuration.companyEmail,
        templateId: 'sendGridid',
        dynamic_template_data: {
        name: customer.customerName,
        device: repair.device,
        accessCode: repair.accessCode,
        storeName: configuration.storeName,
        phone: configuration.phoneNumber,
        },
    };
    console.log('Repair initiated email successfully sent to ' + customer.customerName);
    return await sgMail.send(msg);
  });
```

Comment: Hey, your first code uses [Promise Anti-patterns](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns): a `then` inside another `then`. The second one it's the correct answer !

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that, I have fixed the answer

Comment: i tried the async approach but when doing firebase deploy i got Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Comment: I see, let me fix that, basically, since it's the final part of the call (not wrapped within "then"s), you don't need to return the operation anymore.

Comment: i tried removing the return before but it didnt work, i think its already a firebase issue since i think they use nodeV6, nevertheless, the worst part is that i tried using the first approach using the Promise.all and im still getting null values, i verified it on the firebase console....

Comment: @jackz314 In your 2nd code `onCreate` method should returns a `promise`, so you need to return it. As I seeing on the [documentation](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md#success-failure-errors)  `sgMail` returns a promise.

Comment: @jackz314 In your first code you can destructuring: `const [customer, configuration] = values;` instead of: `const customer = values[0]; const configuration = values[1];`

Comment: @robe007 thanks for the tips, and I totally forgot about how the whole firebase function needs to return

Comment: @naoru I think I got what's going on, eventually, this whole firebase function needs to either be async or return a promise, and if it's async, inside the function you need to return the actual values (await for results), that's why the second way wasn't working if you return a promise instead

Comment: @jackz314 the promises dont resolve and i get a null value... on customer and on configuration